# proving that $\frac{\partial t_k(L(\textbf{x}))}{\partial l_i}=\frac{\partial t_k(\textbf{x})}{\partial x_i}\Bigg|_{\textbf{x}=L(\textbf{x})}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Imagine that I have the following functions: $T,L:\mathbb{R}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, such that: $T(\textbf{x})=(t_1(\textbf{x}),...,t_n(\textbf{x}))$ and $L(\textbf{x})=(l_1(\textbf{x}),...,l_n(\textbf{x}))$ with $\textbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then we can write $(T \circ L)(\textbf{x})$ as:

$$(T \circ L)(\textbf{x})=(t_1(l_1(\textbf{x}),...,l_n(\textbf{x})),...,t_n(l_1(\textbf{x}),...,l_n(\textbf{x})))$$

Or, for short:
$$(T \circ L)(\textbf{x})=(t_1(L(\textbf{x})),...,t_n(L(\textbf{x})))$$

With some examples I got the following equality:

$$\frac{\partial t_k(L(\textbf{x}))}{\partial l_i}=\frac{\partial t_k(\textbf{x})}{\partial x_i}\Bigg|_{\textbf{x}=L(\textbf{x})} \ \ \ \ \ k,i\in \{1,...,n\}$$

But the thing is that I got this equality with some examples. My question is:

1 - Is this true?

2 - If so, how can I prove this?

Comment: Find out what you actually want to compute. You cannot partially differentiate with respect to the $l_i$ since the $l_i$ are not independent variables, but functions.

Comment: But we do that every time when using the chain rule: if $f(x)$ and $u(x)$ are functions, then if $g(x)=f(u(x))$, $\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{df}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$, and $\frac{df}{du}$ is the derivative with respect to $u$ and $u$ is a function

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, by $\frac{\partial t_k(L(\textbf{x}))}{\partial l_i}$ you mean a formal partial derivative of the function 
$t_k(l_1(\textbf{x}),\dots,l_n(\textbf{x}))$ with respect to its $j$-th component $l_j$, that is a partial derivative of the function 
$t_k(\textbf{x})= t_k(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ with respect to its $j$-th component $x_j$, with each $x_i$ later substituted by $l_i(\textbf{x})$, that is with  $\textbf{x}$ substituted by $L(\textbf{x}))$, which is the required equality

$$\frac{\partial t_k(L(\textbf{x}))}{\partial l_i}=\frac{\partial t_k(\textbf{x})}{\partial x_i}\Bigg|_{\textbf{x}=L(\textbf{x})}.$$

Comment: yes that is what I meant. Is that correct? and if so how can i prove it?

Comment: @Eduude As I understood, this is correct because the different sides of the equality are equal, since they both are calculated the same way, described above.